# How can i apply a template to embedded xml in my xsl file?

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, transformation

Something real quick... I have an xslt that applies some transformations to an incoming xml file and transforms it to a pdf file...the problem i am facing is that in my file.xsl i have to have some embedded xml tags to which to apply some templates defined within...how can i achieve this? Sorry for the (probably) silly question but i have no experience with xsl:fo and this came out of the blue for me as a task... here is a sample outline of the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="offer_print.xsl"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                xmlns:data="DOCUMENT">
  <xsl:decimal-format name="european" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="." infinity="--" NaN="--"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:variable name="pcd" select='"31106"'></xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="firstPage" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin-top="2mm" margin-bottom="0.5mm" margin-left="12mm" margin-right="12mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="0.5cm" margin-bottom="0.8cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before extent="4cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="1.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>

                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin-top="2mm" margin-bottom="0.5mm" margin-left="12mm" margin-right="12mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="3.5cm" margin-bottom="0.8cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="complogo"  extent="4cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after1" extent="5.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>

                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="rest" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21.0cm" margin-top="2mm" margin-bottom="0.5mm" margin-left="10.5mm" margin-right="10.5mm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-top="3.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm"/>
                    <fo:region-before region-name="complogo2" extent="3cm"/>
                    <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="1.5cm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>

                <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="basicPSM">
                    <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="first" page-position="first"/>
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" page-position="rest"/>
                        <!-- recommended fallback procedure -->
                        <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rest"/>
                    </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="firstPage">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <xsl:call-template name="first-page"/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="data:data/DOCUMENT">
<!--call templates here -->
<!--and apply to embedded xml -->
</xsl:template>
<!--various other templates and stuff...-->
  <!--my embedded xml-->
<data:data>
<DOCUMENT>
    <SECTIONS>
        <SECTION>
         <HEADER>Just a header</HEADER>
            <PARAGRAPHS>
                <DATA>test</DATA>
                <DATA>testa</DATA>
                <DATA>
                  <LIST> a list element</LIST>
                  <LIST> a list element2</LIST>
                </DATA>
            </PARAGRAPHS>
        </SECTION>
</SECTIONS>
</DOCUMENT>
</data:data>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So how would i access my tags and data in the embedded xml?
It is probably something simple but I lack experience with these kind of stuff....Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help!

So the above has been fixed but now i cannot while the  displays normally the same does not happen with my data tag and list tag... i try to access them using the following :

```
                    <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell border-collapse="collapse">
                        <fo:block/>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell border-collapse="collapse">
                    <xsl:for-each select="PARAGRAPHS">
                            <xsl:for-each select="DATA">
                                <xsl:if test="@type='normal' and ./INFO">
                                    <fo:block space-before="10pt" space-after="10pt" font-size="9pt" text-align="left" font-family="arial">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="INFO"/>
                                    </fo:block>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@type='list' and ./INFO">
                                <fo:list-block provisional-distance-between-starts="2mm">
                                    <xsl:for-each select="INFO">
                                        <fo:list-item>
                                          <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()" text-align="start">
                                            <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="left" font-family="arial">•</fo:block>
                                          </fo:list-item-label>
                                          <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()" text-align="start">
                                            <fo:block font-size="9pt" text-align="left" font-family="arial">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                            </fo:block>
                                          </fo:list-item-body>
                                        </fo:list-item>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </fo:list-block>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block></fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `document('')`, you get the stylesheet's document node, so with `document('')/xsl:stylesheet/data:data/DOCUMENT`, you get that `DOCUMENT` element. And `<xsl:apply-templates select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/data:data/DOCUMENT"/>` would of course then apply-templates to that element. As an alternative you could store the data in a variable or param

```
<xsl:param name="data-doc">
<DOCUMENT>
    <SECTIONS>
        <SECTION>
         <HEADER>Just a header</HEADER>
            <PARAGRAPHS>
                <DATA></DATA>
                <DATA></DATA>
            </PARAGRAPHS>
        </SECTION>
</SECTIONS>
</DOCUMENT>
</xsl:param>
```

and then apply-templates to that: `<xsl:apply-templates select="$data-doc/DOCUMENT"/>`.

Comment: while i managed to load the xml and access node and stuff now for some reason the content in my xml tags <LIST></LIST> and <DATA></DATA> does not display    `<xsl:for-each select="DATA">
          <xsl:if test="@type='normal' and ./INFO">
          <fo:block space-before="10pt" space-after="10pt" font-size="9pt" text-align="left" font-family="arial">
           <xsl:value-of select="DATA"/>
          </fo:block>
-          </xsl:if> `

Comment: Your sample snippet does not have any content in the two DATA elements. But your XSLT in the comment does a `for-each select="DATA"`, and then inside tries `value-of select="DATA"`, you need `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` as the for-each changes the context.

Comment: Sorry i had an error in the sample above...i edited the original post and added some extra info...Thanks for your help so far! 
Can you take a look at the second code snippet i 've added to the original post? what is the error in there? i fail to see it...

Comment: I don't see any `INFO` elements in the nodes included in the stylesheet so I don't know what `for-each select="INFO"` is supposed to do. I think the original question has been answered, if you have further problems down the line then consider asking a new question providing the details like XSLT, XML, output you want versus the one you currently get.

Comment: Yes i figured that out...just took me a while to notice it :D 
Guess i was too tired to see the answer right under my nose...Anyway thank you very much for your help today! I really appreciate it!